# Put bitmap tab in any position

Tags: android, tabs, bitmap, position, fill

Hey all, I've setup a tab layout so that each tab is a custom bitmap of mine.  This is the main java file:

```
public class HelloTabWidget1 extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Resources res = getResources();
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);       
    ImageView imgView1 = new ImageView(this);
    BitmapDrawable bmd1 = new BitmapDrawable();
    bmd1 = (BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.blue);
    imgView1.setImageDrawable(bmd1);
 spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("firsttab").setIndicator(imgView1)
 .setContent(intent);
 tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);       
    ImageView imgView2 = new ImageView(this);
    BitmapDrawable bmd2 = new BitmapDrawable();
        bmd2 = (BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.pink);
        imgView2.setImageDrawable(bmd2);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("secondtab").setIndicator(imgView2)
        .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);       
    ImageView imgView3 = new ImageView(this);
        BitmapDrawable bmd3 = new BitmapDrawable();
            bmd3 = (BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.purple);
            imgView3.setImageDrawable(bmd3);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("thirdtab").setIndicator(imgView3)
            .setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Forthtab.class);       
            ImageView imgView4 = new ImageView(this);
                BitmapDrawable bmd4 = new BitmapDrawable();
                    bmd4 = (BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.red);
                    imgView4.setImageDrawable(bmd4);
                    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("forthtab").setIndicator(imgView4)
                    .setContent(intent);
                    tabHost.addTab(spec);



    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

}

I'm able to get any bitmap I want as a tab, the problem is my original bitmaps were too small to see, once I increased them in size the tabs end up in the middle of the screen with a huge blank black space above it. When I click a black space it changes tabs accordingly.  Is there a way to position it back to the very top and make each bitmap fill a tab?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a temporary solution. I basically kept the code exactly the same, but played around with my image files. I changed my bitmap pictures to png files, but the important thing is the guideline [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_tab.html)  looks like the Android system has an extremely sensitive system for tab icons.  As I said this is a temporary solution, I plan to play with it more.

The only thing I need help with now is having the tabs connected, using png icons at Google's recommended setting of 48 x 48px works, but the tab icons aren't touching.  Looking for a solution to have them touching so they're right next to each other.